# On Click Children Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with jQuery at the moment when it comes to the children of an element that has been dynamically pulled in with AJAX.

So I have the following statement:

```
$('.Select-menu-outer').children().click(function() {
  console.log("tiggered");
});
```

However this does not work for some reason, when I click the children of the `.Select-menu-outer` element nothing happens.

If I use the following statement:

```
$(document).on("click", '.Select-menu-outer', function() {
  console.log("tiggered");
});
```

It triggers however I would like it to trigger on the children of that element. Any idea how I can do this using .on?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Immediate child selector `>` is equivalent to `.children()` method. You need to modify selector to target immediate child elements:

```
$(document).on("click", '.Select-menu-outer > *', function() {
  console.log("tiggered");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is dynamic content you must do the following:

```
//This if you want a specific element within the parents' children
$(document).on('click', '.Select-menu-outer > .Select-menu-inner', function() {
  console.log('A .Select-menu-inner element was clicked');
});

//This if you want all the parents' children
$(document).on('click', '.Select-menu-outer > *', function() {
  console.log('A child element was clicked');
});
```

See this snippet to see the benefits of specifying a inner class

```js
$(document).on('click', '.select-menu-outer > .select-menu-item', function () {
  console.log('clicked %s', $(this).data('title'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="select-menu-outer">
  <li class="select-menu-item" data-title="first">
    First Item
  </li>
  <li class="select-menu-item" data-title="second">
    Second Item
  </li>
  <li class="select-menu-item" data-title="third">
    Third Item
  </li>
  <li class="select-menu-item-no-click">
    Can't Touch This
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

From JQuery `on` method documentation (http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`
>   The majority of browser events bubble, or propagate, from the deepest, innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur all the way up to the body and the document element.
>   
> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>   
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

From Jquery `click` method (http://api.jquery.com/click/):

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler )

So reading those excerpts we can conclude that when you attaching handler by `click` method on children of `.Select-menu-outer` => *The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants.*
So, if `.Select-menu-outer`'s children have no descendants, there no event handling would be.